# What is the best way to kill toads in Read Dead Redemption 2?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In Read Dead Redemption 2, which method or weapon should you use in order to get the best quality toad carcases?

Is it possible to get a perfect carcass?

Answer (score 1):

A toad is considered small game, so you will need to use a bow with a [*small game arrow*](https://reddead.fandom.com/wiki/Bow#Arrows) in order to get a perfect carcass.

This video shows someone killing a toad with the bow.  They seem to pretty much aim right at the middle of the toads body and it yielded a perfect carcass: